# Best practice to report error to jQuery from Spring MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, error-handling

My question is exactly as mentioned in the title. I have Spring webservices returning JSON response. Which of the following is an elegant way of handling errors:

1. Throw an Exception from the Spring MVC controller which will then be handled by the error function of jQuery.
2. Send a JSON response setting for eg. result="failure" and then in the success function of jquery, check on the value of 'result'

   I Would like to understand pros and cons of both approaches.

Thanks

Comment: In first scenarion how exactly you want to hadle Exception with jQuery? Anyway, execptions usually works slowly, so dont throw them when you can.

Comment: exactly like @Bhashit mentioned below by returning HTTP codes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Reporting errors in request-handling via a `success` or some other similar flag is a standard practice in developing web-services. That is, if your request succeeds, that flag in your JSON response indicates `success`, otherwise, it indicates `failure`. There could be other `properties` in your JSON response that can carry an appropriate message, and another field that could carry your result-data if the request succeeds.

When you develop a service this way, the consumers of your web-service are no longer dependent on custom exception-handling. With your first approach, they would have to interpret the `HTTP` codes themselves and determine a course of action based on that. This would, invariably result in a lot of error-handling code on the client-side (possibly duplicated everywhere the services are being used). Rather, with a simple error-flag, they can just examine the flag and determine whether or not the request succeeded, and display appropriate message or take some other action.

I have been involved in dealing with a few web-service (development and consumption), I have *never* dealt with a web-service that depends on the `error` handler of the Ajax-call.

The advantage of your first approach is that you can now really separate out the successful-request from an unsuccessful one. However, in that case, make sure that you handle those exceptions yourself on the server-side and based on those exceptions, return an appropriate status code. If you don't do that, most of the exceptions will result in an `HTTP` error-code of `500` and your web-service clients might be hard-pressed to interpret it in some generic way.

For a small discussion of a proper way of handling errors in your APIs, [see here](https://blog.apigee.com/detail/restful_api_design_what_about_errors).

Answer (score 0):

```
function addCustomer(){
      $.post( "customer/addCustomer", addCustomerForm.serialize() )
     .done(function(data) {
         if(data==='OK'){
             alert( "Customer saved");
         }else{
             alert(data);
         }
      }).fail( function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         alert(textStatus + ":" + errorThrown);
      });
 }

 @RequestMapping(value = "addCustomer", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public  @ResponseBody String addCustomer(

        @RequestParam(required = true, value="add-customer-name") String customerName,
        @RequestParam(required = true, value="add-customer-city-name") String customerCity,
        @RequestParam(required = true, value="add-customer-distributer") String distributerNodeName,
        @RequestParam(required = true, value="add-customer-accountid") String accountId

    ){

    try{

        customersDao.createCustomer(customerName,customerCity, distributerNodeName, accountId);

    }catch(SQLException e){
        logger.error("create customer failed", e);
        return "error:"+e.getMessage();
    }catch(AlreadyExistsException e){
        logger.error("create customer failed", e);
        return "error:"+e.getMessage();
    }catch(QuoteLimitException e){
        logger.error("create customer failed", e);
        return "error:"+e.getMessage();
    }catch(Exception e){
        logger.error("create customer failed", e);
        return "error:"+e.getMessage();
    }

    return "OK";
}
```